# Make slider steps specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a slider which has min `1`, max `24` and steps of `1`. Is it possible I can make the steps as `1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 18, 24`? That's all the values that will be shown when the slider changes left or right.

```html
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id="ex1Slider" type="text" data-bind="sliderValue: {value: loanperiod, min:0, max: 24, step: 1, formatter:formatter1}, event: { change: $root.getInvestmentDetailsForBorrower }, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' " style="display: none;">
```

Slider has knockout.js binding.

If needed then I am adding the slider binding here

```
// Custom binding for slider value
    (function ($) {

        ko.bindingHandlers.sliderValue = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var params = valueAccessor();

        // Check whether the value observable is either placed directly or in the paramaters object.
        if (!(ko.isObservable(params) || params['value']))
            throw "You need to define an observable value for the sliderValue. Either pass the observable directly or as the 'value' field in the parameters.";

        // Identify the value and initialize the slider
        var valueObservable;
        if (ko.isObservable(params)) {
            valueObservable = params;
            $(element).slider({value: ko.unwrap(params)});
        }
        else {
            valueObservable = params['value'];
            if (!Array.isArray(valueObservable)) {
                // Replace the 'value' field in the options object with the actual value
                params['value'] = ko.unwrap(valueObservable);
                $(element).slider(params);
            }
            else {
                valueObservable = [params['value'][0], params['value'][1]];
                params['value'][0] = ko.unwrap(valueObservable[0]);
                params['value'][1] = ko.unwrap(valueObservable[1]);
                $(element).slider(params);
            }
        }

        // Make sure we update the observable when changing the slider value
        $(element).on('slide', function (ev) {
            if (!Array.isArray(valueObservable)) {
                valueObservable(ev.value);
            }
            else {
                valueObservable[0](ev.value[0]);
                valueObservable[1](ev.value[1]);
            }
        }).on('change', function (ev) {
            if (!Array.isArray(valueObservable)) {
                valueObservable(ev.value.newValue)
            }
            else {
                valueObservable[0](ev.value.newValue[0]);
                valueObservable[1](ev.value.newValue[1]);
            }
        });

        // Clean up
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).slider('destroy');
            $(element).off('slide');
        });

            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        var valueObservable;
        if (ko.isObservable(modelValue))
            valueObservable = modelValue;
        else
            valueObservable = modelValue['value'];

        if (!Array.isArray(valueObservable)) {
            $(element).slider('setValue', parseFloat(valueObservable()));
        }
        else {
            $(element).slider('setValue', [parseFloat(valueObservable[0]()),parseFloat(valueObservable[1]())]);
        }
            }
        };

    })(jQuery);

    // Custom binding for slider
    (function ($) {

        ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                  var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
                  $(element).slider(options);
                  ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function (event, ui) {
                          var observable = valueAccessor();
                          observable(ui.value);
                  });
                  ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                          $(element).slider("destroy");
                  });
                  ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function (event, ui) {
                          var observable = valueAccessor();
                          observable(ui.value);
                  });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                  var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                  if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
                  $(element).slider("value", value);

            }
        };

    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to have a function that takes the raw slider value and translates it to your custom values. Then use the result of that wherever you need the value.

```js
vm = {
  sliderValues: [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 18, 24],
  rawSliderValue: ko.observable(1),
  sliderValue: ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return vm.sliderValues[vm.rawSliderValue() - 1];
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" data-bind="attr {max: sliderValues.length}, value: rawSliderValue, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
<div data-bind="text: sliderValue"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for showing me, but is it possible I could just take the max attribute and put it on my slider? then it would give mess less trouble

Comment: can i use it like attr {max : 1,2,3,4,12,18,24} ??

Comment: No, max is just a number to indicate the maximum value the slider can produce. You could make the max 24, but it would allow all the values from 1 to 24. Then you could subscribe a function to change any invalid value to the nearest valid value, but that's more trouble and uglier than this.

Comment: I got what you mean, but can you show me how to write that function without binding it to VM? then it would make things easier for me, since I am using one js file for alot of pages, and they are appliedbinding with a ID in the html

Comment: You can put the conversion inside your binding handlers, since that seems to be where you manage the value. You'll need to handle converting raw values to and from your custom values so that you can handle changes in the slider and in the observable.

Comment: Is it possible you could help me out ? I copied the blinder off the internet so I am not sure what does what

Comment: Where is `loanperiod` defined? That's where you would add the definition for `sliderValue`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, for now loan period is just in an observable like this 
self.loanperiod = ko.observable(24);
Its a value that I am thorwing to the database afterwards through ajax, but let me know if more information is required

Comment: If you can make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem, I can give you some help with it.